# How to call the distribution of coin values within a currency

Tags: single-word-requests

There are many special words surrounding coins.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_numismatics) lists a view. 
I'm interested in a name for the distribution of coin values in a currency.

The Euro has 1ct, 2ct, 5ct, 10ct, 20ct, 50ct, 1€, 2€ pieces.

Harry Potter has 1knut, 29knut, 493knut pieces.

And I want a name for that. 1 word is appreciated, if there is none, multi-word terms are ok, as well.

**Update**:
so far, we got(order has no meaning):

- (set of|circulating|range of|available) (coin) denominations
- denomination (set|list|mix)
- circulated denominations
- (denominations|coin types) in circulation
- coinage system
- coin (range|palette|coterie)
- currency genus[proposed, not seen]

ambiguous
(can also mean mass of all coins existing e.g. all 1ct + all 2ct...):

- coin species
- (circulating) coinage
- coins in circulation

Comment: circulating coinage?

Comment: Related: ["What this country needs is an 18¢ piece"](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/change2.pdf),  J. Shallit: *Mathematical Intelligencer* v. 25, pp 20–23.

Comment: I believe there **is not** a word for "the set of denominations". Never encountered one in say coin investment.  I would just call it "the denomination set" or the "set of denominations"

Comment: @user2740: you forgot "species" in your collected suggestions.

Comment: @DanBron: sorry, I read "several problems" and skipped the paragraph. But it is of course as clear as "coins in circulation", so I made an extra list for ambiguous terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the US Mint and related sources on currency systems, there doesn't appear to be a specific term of art for the set of coin values or denominations; this set appears to be referred to in prose in various, similar ways:

- *[circulating or regular issue] **coin denominations*** ([US Mint](http://www.usmint.gov/about_the_mint/fun_facts/?action=fun_facts1))
- ***coin types*** [in [common] circulation] ([numismatic glossary](http://www.acoin.com/regular.htm))

Note the words in brackets here only qualify the coins as part of the "normal" set (i.e. not special coins like obsolete denominations, collectors' coins, proof coins, etc), but do not name the set itself. Even the original [United States Coinage Act of 1792](http://nesara.org/files/coinage_act_1792.pdf) refers to the set indirectly:

> *Be it ... enacted that there shall be .. struck and coined .. coins of gold, silver, and copper, of the **following denominations**: Eagles ($10), Half Eagles ($5), Quarter Eagles ($2.50), Dollars, Half Dollars, Quarter Dollars, Dismes (now with an extra `s`!), Half Dismes (nickles), cents, half-cents*

However, the Act does contain another word which you might make use of: "***Species*** of coins to be struck: Eagle, Half-Eagles...", and in fact the OED says the word used to mean

> A particular kind or sort of coin or money. Obs.

So, you might be able to use "***coin species***" this way; however, that term suffers from several problems (besides being obsolete).  First, coin species were normally distinguished by their composition -- the metal they were struck from  -- rather than their denomination, which was a separate concept ("gold specie consisting of 10 dollar, 5 dollar, and 2.5 dollar denominations; silver specie consisting of 1 dollar, 50 cent....").  Second, "[***specie***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/specie?showCookiePolicy=true)" (now we use the singular for coin money, and typically apply the plural *species* in a biological context) is just as ambiguous as "coinage" or "coins in circulation", because one the one hand, it may refer to the *types of coins*, but it also may refer to the *existing mass of coins*; it doesn't distinguish between abstract concept of "coins" and the physical objects "coins".¹

So numismatics and currency lingo appears to be a dead end.  Taking another tack, then there is a famous computer science problem which studies the properties of systems of coin denominations, the "[*Change-making problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)".

Chasing down a few of the seminal papers on this problem, unfortunately, it turns out denomination selections are still referred to indirectly, using prose (though now of a more mathematical bent), rather than provided with a unique term of art.  Most frequently we encounter "[*sets of coin denominations*](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/change2.pdf)", and similar phrases.

However, [one reference](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~ek266745/notatki/coinmachine.pdf) uses the more concise term "***coinage system***", which I prefer, for its combination of brevity and clarity (it's a self-evident term). The term "***coin range***", as @JoeBlow suggests, is clear and sharp as well.

---

But perhaps, if you're willing to take a bit of license, you could the set of all coin species the "*currency **genus***"?

---

**UPDATE**: Based on [this answer about Imperial units](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193425/55623), and the Wikipedia page it links to, you might consider "***radix***" (meaning the total, ordered set of values which lend denominations to your coins).

Comment: The denominations are the individual values of coins. I think user2740 was looking for a term to describe the whole group.

Comment: Ah, thanks, missed that.  Since this answer is incomplete and your answer includes the word "denomination" anyway, I think I'll delete this one until I come up with a better idea.

Comment: Dan, I think "coinage system" is a bit more general (ie, it would include things like "we use brass!" or whatever).  the "coinage system" would include as a decision the "set of denominations".  I believe it's very clear what the OP is asking (word for "the set of denominations") and, I really don't think there's a word.  Obviously you could use other words that set such as **range** of denominations, **available** denominations, denomination **list**, **mix**, etc.

Comment: @joe, I don't think there's a single word either (and I looked pretty hard!), which is why I was suggesting a multi-word term. That said, we would still like to keep the term as brief as possible (meaning minimizing the total number of  words, or better, syllables). For this particular answer, I chose to adhere to the sources, and the shortest/best I could find in the relevant literature was "coinage system" (which, if you click though, you'll see unambiguously refers to the set of denominations, in a rigorous, mathematical sense). That said, I really like "*coin range*", and will suggest it.

Comment: good one, Dan ...

Comment: hey what about denomination palette - i like it!  :)

Comment: Let's not go nuts here, Joe ;)

Comment: Ah hah!  @DanBron I finally thought of a useful word here, **coterie**.

Comment: Haha, I can just picture Washington's head gossiping with Lincoln's about Roosevelt ("He's looking *so thin* these days, poor man").

Comment: Lol excellent.  i just realised that, indeed just as you utilise coterie really best relates to, not unlike say "clique", a group of people.  but I suppose it's often used in data-and-similar discussions (essentially as a synonym for "set" or "group") - I guess, I've used it more that way, in life.  Again it's not unlike "palette" in the way I'm suggesting using it.  Cheers!

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard is used that way. But I'm definitely going to drop it into a few conversations at work! Thanks. BTW, why don't you add an answer and include "coin palette" and "coin coterie"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a single term in English that will fit what you're talking about, but something that gets close is the term **circulated denominations** or **denominations in circulation**.

Literally, this just means the [denominations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denomination_%28currency%29) of the currency (the "coin values") that are out there (in *circulation*). For example, you'd use a sentence like this:

> The Euro has denominations of 1¢, 2¢, 5¢, 10¢, 20¢, 50¢, 1€, and 2€ in circulation.
>
> Canada recently removed the 1¢ denomination from circulation, so the penny is no longer a possible coin value of Canadian currency.

Answer (score 0):

Just FTR, I finally thought of a word here, **coterie**.

Coterie tends to mean "set of humans":

so, some sort of set of people (perhaps friends, countrymen - whatever) that are grouped together in some particular way, relating to the discussion at hand.

For example the word would be used often by economists or social-studies types, or by anthropologists.

However, you use "coterie" all the time in computing, to mean, I suppose basically a "set" of any things (not necessarily people) that are available, that go together for a specific purpose, a "range of available" blah.

So, FWIW, that's a term I would use in describing this particular set or group of things.

(You can imagine a sentence like "given the coterie of denominations, how can we guess what the typical distribution will be in a person's pocket after a day of shopping..." or whatever.)

---

Additionally, as mentioned in a comment "palette" could be useful here. Again I've seen that used to describe perhaps an array of "available items" (perhaps numbers, denominations, sizes - whatever) from a broader range.