# Term for systems of measure with arbitrary units

Tags: terminology

What is the term for systems of measure whose units are not simple scalings by magnitude, but instead "arbitrary" units, that is, units unrelated by magnitude?

I'd regard metric lengths scaling simply by magnitude.  For the purpose of this question, I'd regard imperial lengths (foot, yard, mile) and common time reckoning (hour, day, week, month, year) as arbitrary.

Comment: The question is unclear.  There is nothing more continuous about metric lengths than imperial lengths. What can be said is that metric units of a given type are decimal multiples of each other. But *continuous* and *discontinuous* are not appropriate terms for this, IMO. And I don't know of a term that distinguishes units in this way.

Comment: @Drew, right — that's why I need help with terminology. :)  Edited.

Comment: By "arbitrary units", do you mean things like the media telling us that the Islamic State is now the size of [insert ridiculously large number here] ***football pitches, Wales, whales*** or whatever?

Comment: The word non-decimal exists, and I'd say works here (I don't know of any existing system of units arranged along the lines of say 7 bilbos = 1 gimli, 7 gimlis = 1 aragorn, 7 aragorns = 1 elrond ... ie constant scale factors not equal to 10).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, no, I mean that the units are not arranged by a simple scaling of magnitude.  I also mean to consider only commonly used systems of measure.

Comment: May I suggest changing the title? "What is the generic term for systems of measure where units are not static decimal multiples of each other?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, the metric system uses a *fixed* (or *standard*, or *ordinary*) *radix* (or *base*), whereas the imperial system uses a "***mixed radix***" (or synonyms per the preceding).

From [Wikipedia's article on mixed radix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix):

> **Mixed radix numeral systems** are non-standard positional numeral systems in which **the numerical base varies from position to position.**
>
> The most familiar example of mixed radix systems is in **timekeeping and calendars**. Western time radices include decimal centuries, decades and years as well as duodecimal months, trigesimal (and untrigesimal) days, overlapped with base 52 weeks and septenary days.
>
> A second example of a mixed radix numeral system in current use is in **the design and use of currency**, where a limited set of denominations are printed or minted with the objective of being able to represent any monetary quantity; the amount of money is then represented by the number of coins or banknotes of each denomination. When deciding which denominations to create (and hence which radices to mix), a compromise is aimed for between a minimal number of different denominations, and a minimal number of individual pieces of coinage required to represent typical quantities. So, for example, in the UK, banknotes are printed for £50, £20, £10 and £5, and coins are minted for £2, £1, 50p, 20p, 10p, 5p, 2p and 1p—these follow the 1-2-5 series of preferred values.

[Wolfram Mathworld](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MixedRadixNumberRepresentations/) goes a little deeper into to the construction of such systems:

> In conventional positional notation systems, a numeral written as has the value  where  is called the radix or base of the number system. The multipliers for each digit thus proceed from right to left in geometric sequence and each is a constant  multiplied by the multiplier of the digit to the right. This representation of numbers is often extremely convenient. *There are instances, however, where it is useful to denote a numeric quantity where the **ratio between the multiplier of a digit and the digit on its right is not necessarily a constant***. Such representation systems are called mixed radix or mixed base number systems. This Demonstration shows how numbers represented in conventional positional notation systems can be represented as a mixed base form.

Alternatively, the 1860 paper "[*Walkingame's Arithmetic*](http://www.lloffion.org.uk/docs/walkingames_arithmetic/walkingames_arithmetic.pdf)" uses the term "***Compound Units***".

Comment: Fine answer. Mathematically, the base 52 isn't used, as 'there are fifty-two weeks in a year' is a fiction or an approximation, depending on your viewpoint.